# Using special symbols in HTML and Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, utf-8, ascii

I'm trying to figure out what is the proper way to use the "not" operator (Negation) which looks like: ¬ (UTF-8: `U+00AC`) in JavaScript. I could use:

```
<span>¬A</span>
```

But I'm not sure if it is the proper way and if its been supported on all (or most) of the modern browsers and mobile. I tried to find a previous topic on this matter but could not find any. The wanted result is to display this operator beside `A`.

Answer (score 2):

Correct escape sequences for HTML are: &#x00AC, followed by ';A', and for javascript - either '\xACA' or '\u00ACA'.

"meta charset" is always advisable to include, but it does not affect the escapes.

I added ';' after the HTML escape sequence: for some reason it wasn't needed if instead of 'A' there is, for example, 'k', I didn't know. Semicolon has to be added.

Answer (score 0):

*If* you are properly using UTF-8 (which is to say that your HTML, JS, and CSS files are all encoded in UTF-8, `<meta charset="utf-8">` is present in the `<head>`, and HTTP headers all define the charset as UTF-8), there should be no need to encode the symbol at all. Simply write `¬`, exactly as you have done here.

The only symbols you *need* to encode are `<` and `&` (also `'` and/or `"` in attributes). Most would also recommend encoding `>` and the non-breaking space, to avoid confusion. I encode all of these, but nothing else.

Comment: I actually encode quotation marks everywhere, not just in attributes. It does no harm, and it makes my life simpler to have only one encoding method to use everywhere.

Comment: Yes, that would be correct. I used it just once before without ';' and for some reason it worked. May be quirk. And about <meta charset="utf-8">: IIS doesn't care, but HttpListener simply doesn't work without it. Better to add and every time. - thanks